# Vue - passing data via Event.$emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a question about passing data through Event.$emit. I have a parent that has a click event (appSelected) like this

```
<template>
    <v-app>
    <v-container>
    <v-select :items="results" item-text="name" item-value="id" v-model="selectedOption" @change="appSelected"
          :results="results"
          label="Choose Application"
          dense
     ></v-select>
     </v-container>
    </v-app>
  </template>
```

In that component I have a method that emits the data. This is the id - this.selectedOption

```
 appSelected() {
   //alert("This is the id" + this.selectedOption);
   Event.$emit('selected', this.selectedOption);
```

In my child component I would like to pass and use the value but can't seem to get it to work. I have a v-if on the top level div that if it sees a true it will show all below. That works great, but I need the id that's being passed.

This works for showing the div, but need to pass and use the id also. How can I pass the and use the id?

```
 Event.$on('selected', (data) => this.appselected = true);
```

```
<template>
 <div v-if="appselected">
 Choose the Client Source
  <input type="text" placeholder="Source client" v-model="query" 
  v-on:keyup="autoComplete"
  v-on-clickaway="away"
  @keydown.esc="clearText" class="form-control">
   <span class="instructiontext"> Search for id, name or coid</span>
  <div class="panel-footer" v-if="results.length">
   <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" v-for="result in results">
   <a href="#" @click="getClient(result.name)">{{ result.name + "-" + result.oid }} </a>
    </li>
   
   </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { directive as onClickaway } from 'vue-clickaway';
 export default{
  directives: { 
    onClickaway: onClickaway,
  },
  
  data(){
   return {
    add_id: '',
    onSelecton: '',
    input_disabled: false,
    selected: '',
    query: '',
    results: [],
    appselected: false
   }
  },
  methods: {
   
    getClient(name) {
        this.query = name;
        this.results = [];
    },
      
    clearText(){
        this.query = '';
    },
     away: function() {
      // Added for future use
    },
    autoComplete(){
    this.results = [];
    if(this.query.length > 2){
     axios.get('/getclientdata',{params: {query: this.query}}).then(response => {
      this.results = response.data;
      
     });
    }
   }
  },

  created() {
     Event.$on('selected', (data) => this.appselected = true);
     console.log(this.appselected);
    }
  
 }
</script>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your listener to do something with the emitted value.  I see the parent already has a `selected` variable that you maybe intend to use for this purpose:

```js
Event.$on('selected', (selectedOption) => {
  this.selected = selectedOption;
  this.appselected = true;
});
```

The `selectedOption` is the value emitted from the child.